# How to export AWS S3 URL to CSV for images I uploaded there via Scrapy?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scrapy, image-uploading

I have successfully uploaded images to AWS S3 via Scrapy using the `ImagesPipeline`. Now the problem is, the AWS S3 image URLs are not showing up when I export the scraped info to CSV.

How can I make sure the AWS S3 image URLs to be exported to the CSV?

Comment: Do your items contains the S3 URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution myself! It turns out I forget to add a simple setting. I don't want to use the default image field name. I want to use `Images` instead of `images`, so I have to put this setting in `settings.py`:

```
IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD = 'Images'
```